# splitting text and wrapping with span class using js prototype

Tags: prototypejs

I have a date inside a div tag and I want to split the text and wrap the second half of the text in a span tag with a class id on it.

```
<div class="date"> Wednesday, August 17</div>
```

I need everything after the comma to be wrapped in a span tag with a class like this.

```
<span class="highlight">August 17</span>
```

In its entire html it would look like this.

```
<div class="date"> Wednesday, <span class="highlight">August 17</span></div>
```

How would I go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like (my prototype fu is weak but this works):

```
var div = $$('div.date')[0];
var parts = div.innerText.split(', ');

var html = parts[0] + ', <span class="highlight">' + parts[1] + '</span>';
div.innerHTML = html;
```

Here's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/3Rc8U/3/

Comment: Thanks Mrchief your prototype skills are better than mine. I usually use jquery but for this one taks I have to work on someone else s files using prototype. div.innerText is undefined. By using innerHTML it works. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Chapsterj: :) There is nothing prototype-ish about the code except the `$$` part. WOrking with jQuery is a bliss! (think `wrapInner`)!